# How can I check out just the trunks of multiple projects from the same repository?

Tags: svn

We have a single SVN repository with multiple related projects. Like so...

```
\repo
  \Project1
    \branches
    \tags
    \trunk
  \Project2
    \branches
    \tags
    \trunk
  \Project3
    \branches
    \tags
    \trunk
```

I would like to check out the trunk of each project into my workspace without the branches/tags folders.

```
\workspace
  \Project1
    \trunk
  \Project2
    \trunk
  \Project3
    \trunk
```

Is there a way to do this without checking each trunk out individually?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Long answer: See http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html and do your checkouts in a looped script.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to hear... :-( but thanks for the quick and accurate response any way.  Looks like I'll be writing a script today.

Comment: I found a batch file to automate the process.  http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2008/03/11/batch-file-to-checkout-all-root-level-project-trunks-in-a-subversion-repository.aspx

Comment: The batch file is great for those of us stuck on Windows.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the -N option, which ignores subdirectories. You can run this the very first time you check out the sources:

```
svn co -N http://path/to/repo
cd repo
for f in Project1 Project2 Project3; do
  svn up -N $f
  svn up $f/trunk
done
```

And to update the trunks at a later time:

```
svn up repo/*/trunk
```

This works with all SVN clients. If you're using an SVN 1.5.x client, you can also have a look at "sparse directories", documented at *[Sparse Directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html)* (I'm not allowed to post links yet :-C), which will allow you to run "svn update" in the repository directory.

Answer (score 6):

This did the trick nicely in bash.  Note that I renamed the output folders to make Eclipse happier when importing the projects.

```
for f in `svn ls http://path/to/repo`; do svn checkout http://path/to/repo/${f}trunk $f; done
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: check out the [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re04.html) for the sections below

Check out 2 different directories into two separate working copies:

```
$ svn checkout file:///tmp/repos/test  file:///tmp/repos/quiz
A  test/a
A  test/b
Checked out revision 2.
A  quiz/l
A  quiz/m
Checked out revision 2.
$ ls
quiz  test
```

Check out 2 different directories into two separate working copies, but place both into a directory called 'working copies':

```
$ svn checkout file:///tmp/repos/test  file:///tmp/repos/quiz working-copies
A  working-copies/test/a
A  working-copies/test/b
Checked out revision 2.
A  working-copies/quiz/l
A  working-copies/quiz/m
Checked out revision 2.
$ ls
working-copies
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you'll still have to tell it about (checkout) each individual trunk - but you can at least also check out the workspace (to get all the projects, and so you can update, etc. globally) using [sparse directories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html).

Answer (score 0):

Found this to be working rather than the above:

```
checkoutList.bat:

for %%G in (projectA, projectB, projectC) do (
  echo %%G
  mkdir %%G
  svn co http://your.repo/path/%%G/trunk %%G
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows batch script:

```
@echo off
for /f %%G in ('svn ls https://path/to/main/folder/') do (
    mkdir %%G
    cd %%G
    echo Checking out [%%G] project
    svn co https://path/to/main/folder/%%Gtrunk
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this PowerShell script to checkout all the "trunk" folders in arbitrarily nested projects. Just supply `$rootUrl` and `$rootDir` values, and run the script.

```
$rootUrl = "https://<svn-server>/<repo-path>/"
$rootDir = "<local path to checkout into>"

# Usually, when there is a folder called "trunk" somewhere, adjacent folders
# are tags/branches, so we don't need to recurse into them.
# If this is not desired, change below variable to $false
$ignoreTrunkSiblings = $true

function FindAndCheckoutTrunk($url, $dir) {
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkGray $url

    $childItems = Invoke-Expression "svn list `"$url`""
    $foundTrunk = $false
    $trunk = $childItems | Where-Object { IsTrunk $_ }
    if($trunk) {
        $foundTrunk = $true
        Checkout $url $dir $trunk
    }

    if($foundTrunk -and $ignoreTrunkSiblings) {
        return
    }

    foreach ($childItem in $childItems) {
        if(-not $childItem.EndsWith("/")) {
            # skip files
            continue
        }
        if(IsTrunk $childItem) {
            # we already checked-out this trunk folder
            continue
        }

        $subUrl = $url + $childItem
        $subDir = JoinPath $dir $childItem
        FindAndCheckoutTrunk $subUrl $subDir
    }
}

function IsTrunk($dir) {
    return $dir.TrimEnd('/').Equals("trunk", [System.StringComparison]::InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
}

function Checkout($baseUrl, $baseDir, $childDirName) {
    $subUrl = $baseUrl + $childDirName
    $subDir = JoinPath $baseDir $childDirName

    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan $subUrl
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Found trunk. Checking out..."

    $cmd = "svn checkout `"$subUrl`" `"$subDir`""
    Invoke-Expression $cmd
}

function JoinPath($path1, $path2) {
    return [System.IO.Path]::Join($path1, $path2)
}


FindAndCheckoutTrunk $rootUrl $rootDir
```

Answer (score -1):

Right click on folder - SVN Check out.
Place your URL and click "Choose Item" button.
With the check boxes select the sub-folders that you want to include.

Comment: You instructions are for what OS and what tool? Tortoise?