# SVN: How do I checkout entire source tree with trunks only?

Tags: svn, version-control

Two-parter, really:

1. How do I checkout an entire source tree but only get the trunks of everything, ignoring all branches and tags?
2. Assuming #1 is doable, is there a way to have there not be any "trunk" directories, and just have the files reside in a folder with the name of the repository?

Answer (score 31):

Most SVN repostiories are structured something like this:

```
/
|-- /branches
|-- /tags
`-- /trunk
    |-- foo
    `-- bar
```

So if the root of the repository is at http://www.example.com/svn, you can run

```
svn co http://www.example.com/svn/trunk
```

to check out just the trunk.  If you want to name the checked-out folder after the project, just add the project name to the command line:

```
svn co http://www.example.com/svn/trunk myproject
```

This command should produce a directory structure like:

```
myproject/
|-- foo
`-- bar
```

Comment: I cannot agree. In your tree you have only one project. The question was to get only trunk*S* - plural - i assume there are many projects in one folder in SVN.

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not possible. What you can do is to create a new project add define external links from it to every other projects trunks. External link works like softlink.

You can then chekout everything in one step.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/ch07s03.html

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it is not correct.  What the questioner is asking for is certainly possible, by doing what is described in Nick Meyer's answer or by creating multiple working copies.  I also think the suggestion to use `svn:externals` is not a good workaround.

Comment: Since the original questioner did not provide details of what he/she is trying to accomplish, I think it is worthwhile to suggest the svn:externals solution. In certain situations, it might be the best solution.

Answer (score 4):

Provided all folders have identical root-structure you can use this batch command in Windows to check out all trunk folders from the root:

```
for /F %%A IN ('svn list <your root URL here>') do svn co <your root URL here>/%%Atrunk ./%%A
```

Comment: works, just make sure you use a single % if not in a batch file but on the command line and trunk is case sensitive, in my case it had to be TRUNK
If username and password are required you need to add them too

Answer (score 1):

This script creates a subscript with all checkout commands of the underlying projects (depth is DEVELOPMENT -> FOLDER -> SVN PROJECTS)

```
#!/bin/bash

PROJECTS=`svn list http://svn-server/svn/hps/Development/`

IFS=$'\n' 
for i in $PROJECTS; do
 REPOS=`svn list http://svn-server/svn/hps/Development/$i`
 for r in $REPOS; do
  echo "svn checkout \"http://svn-server/svn/hps/Development/${i}${r}trunk\" \"${r}\"" >> checkout_all_svn_trunk_cmd.sh
 done;
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I wrote [this answer for this specific issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76175800/1174942). It traverses all the subfolders and checks-out every folder named "trunk".
2. Just modify the script so that the local folder does not contain the name "trunk".